# Can't set TreeCtrl Object Properties on Treeview ActiveX object in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm testing out the Treeview activeX object on an MS-Access form. The treeview itself works fine, but when opening the Treeview's TreeCtrl Object Properties window, the window loads but all the option are blank. This is happening in Access 2013.

I have a laptop running Access 2010 and all the options are there as choices in that version.

Any ideas on what might causing this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Access 2013 on Windows 7 32-bit. Also, ActiveX events for the control are not firing as expected, even with accdb files which are known to work on other computers.

Answer (score 1):

There were some problems last summer (August 2012) with MSCOMCTL.OCX that affected the Treeview control. You might want to try the fix described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986), which involves

- deleting an obsolete registry entry, and then
- manually (re-)registering the Mscomctl.ocx file

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem was resolved by running:

`regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX`

as administrator, then logging out, and logging back in. Deteling the registry entry was not required. I tested this with Access 2013 32-bit on Windows 7 32-bit.

Unfortunately, this issue still appears on other computers running Access 2013, even after compiling and saving as an executable accde. Not all of my users will have administrator privileges, and I can't expect them to register an OCX whenever they install the application.

However, if you download the FixIt from Microsoft's [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597986), you can run it without Administrator privileges and it also seems to resolve the problem without re-logging.

Comment: Does anyone know why Microsoft wouldn't just issue a patch through Windows Update to fix this? It's more than a year later and users are still experiencing this problem. They shouldn't have to modify their registry or run a FixIt just to use an application.